# Convert JSON data to a Data Frame

Tags: python, json, dataframe, parsing

I need to convert the JSON data at the bottom which I got as response from a API call into a data frame.
I need the data to be like:

```
   v   v   name    Age
   --------------------
0  1a  1c   sam    10
1  2a  2c   tom    40
```

I tried using df = pd.json_normalize(response.json(), record_path=['rows']).
But all the data is going into many rows and only one column. Would help if i can change the v's into another column name.

```
"rows": [
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": "1a"
                },
                {
                    "v": "[{ "name" : "sam", "Age" = "10"}]"
                },
                {
                    "v": "1c"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": "2a"
                },
                {
                    "v": "[{ "name" : "tom", "Age" = "40"}]"
                },
                {
                    "v": "2c"
                }
                
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have JSON data that includes JSON strings as data?  Or is that just typed wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately. I actually do have it. I just changed the data but the structure is same.

Answer (score 1):

You just do it a line at a time.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

x = json.load( open('x.json'))
print(x)
#{'rows': [{'f': [{'v': '1a'}, {'v': '1b'}, {'v': '1c'}]}, {'f': [{'v': '2a'}, {'v': '2b'}, {'v': '2c'}]}]}

data = [[r['v'] for r in row['f']] for row in x['rows']]
print(data)
#[['1a', '1b', '1c'], ['2a', '2b', '2c']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. 
I just updated the JSON data. What if there is one more level?